# "unable to run mksdcard sdk tool" android studio ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

I have installed all the 32-bit libraries need for installation, yet i get the above error message and the following errors on the terminal

```
pawanjot@pawanjot-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads/android-studio/bin$ ./studio.sh
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@5fa7e7ff for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/home/pawanjot/Downloads/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /home/pawanjot/.AndroidStudio2.1/system/tmp/jna-1314605980/jna6525310034260149415.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /home/pawanjot/.AndroidStudio2.1/system/tmp/jna-1314605980/jna6525310034260149415.tmp
[  23305]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /home/pawanjot/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
[  33321]   WARN - ome.install.ComponentInstaller - File /home/pawanjot/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
```

Comment: Why did you get the 32 bit libraries? Your JVM says 64-bit

Comment: @cricket_007 Because those were the instructions given by the official android site.
Check out on the following link.

https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Comment: Now that you edited the question, those are only warnings, no errors.

Comment: But i am still getting the dialogue box popping with error "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool. One common reason for this is missing 32 bit compatibility libraries.
Please fix the underlying issue and retry."

Comment: You could try to run `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/mksdcard` yourself as see what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Add the required libraries try with this link http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/linux-32-bit-libraries

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1
```

Comment: Resolved the issue by myself with sheer luck. 
I changed server of ubuntu in software and updates settings from "main server" to "server from India" . Then I ran the command sudo apt-get update. After that ran the command sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 . 
And Voila ! No errors. :) 

Thank you for the answer anyway, I really appreciate it. :)